# "phpjs" strpos function not returning true

Tags: javascript, php

In translating a php script to js, I've used some functions from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org).
However, it seems that the 'strpos' function does not return true under the same conditions.

```
$string = "aaa:bbb";
$colons = strpos($string, ":");
echo $colons;
if ($colons == true)
    {echo "yup";}
```

echoes "3yup", however:

```
var string = "aaa:bbb";
var colons = strpos(string, ":");
console.log(colons);    
if (colons == true)
    {console.log("yup");}
```

only echoes "3".

Is this my mistake, a bug, or aspect of how javascript handles?
And in any case, what method is recommended to get a `true` result for the presence of a colon in `string`?

Thanks!

Comment: because in JavaScript 3 is not equal to true

Comment: apparently in php it is! :)

Comment: It's your if statement [`3 != true`](http://jsfiddle.net/vFRzG/) in javascript

Comment: @Jason Sperske Ok - so if I'm understanding you correctly, it's something about js itself, as distinct from php. Can you say a bit more about why/how this is the case? (Some terms might help me here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both php and the phpjs implementation are returning the correct value (3) but the semantics of `==` are different.

The equivalent JS for the test `$colons == true` is:

```
Boolean(colons) == true
```

Comment: that works, though I'll have to study to understand why. Thanks!

Comment: @GregoryTippett The exact details are described [in the JS spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and [in the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), but to put it simply: the boolean `true` is promoted to the integer `1` in the comparison in JS, whereas in PHP the integer is demoted to the boolean `true`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get string presence based on `strpos`, then I suppose you can do the following:

```
if (strpos(string, ":") != false) {
    console.log("string exists!");
}
```

Comment: Of course... yes that works, thanks! Any idea why I'm not getting `true`?

Comment: javascript treats booleans and integers differently, while PHP treats all non-zero as a ``true``.

Comment: Thanks - just to note, on closer inspection, if the colon was in the first position of the string, it would *not* trigger the "string exists" statement.

Answer (score -3):

strpos() in JS doesn't return true. Instead it returns the position, In your case it will return 4.

Comment: interestingly, the `strpos` function from phpjs *does* return `false` (test it in the console)... just not `true`.